# How to replace key-pair used to access AWS EC2 machines

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, key-pair

How to replace key-pair used to access AWS EC2 machines.
We have 3 machines (machineA, machineB, machineC) all using the same key-pair for SSH access. How can we replace this to a new key-pair

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to use new key-pair to access ec2 machine:

Generate public-private key pair from within your instance. Sample command if using amazon linux2 to generate keypair:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Append the newly generated public key to .ssh/authorized_keys file

```
cat newkeypair.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now you will need to download the private key part. One way would be to give AmazonS3FullAccess role to ec2instance and upload the private key part to a bucket as below

```
aws s3 cp newkeypair s3://my-bucket
```

After downloading the private key part to your local machine, change its permission and connect with your ec2-instance

```
chmod 400  newkeypair
ssh -i newkeypair ec2-user@instance-public-ip
```